# What is the best way to store image in SQL Server if the size of image is too large?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to store image having size 3GB in SQL Server?

I know it seems like unrealistic scenario but I am curious to know if its possible to save the image in database in any way ?

Comment: I would suggest store Image in Application Directory and store its path in SQLserver

Comment: yes I know the same. But I want to know if its possible to store the image in database ?

Comment: You **cannot** store anything larger than 2 GB in a SQL Server table - the `varbinary(max)` datatype to handle binary data (like files) has a hard, system-given 2 GB limit ([official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) on  `varbinary`). If you have files larger than 2 GB, you need to use the `FILESTREAM` functionality in SQL Server

Comment: @marc_s that page isn't about FILESTREAM. The correct page is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx#storage) - the 2 GB limit doesn't apply for filestream storage

Comment: Oh, I think it's not so unrealistic. First, replace *Image* by *Video*, and you are already there. And picture are getting bigger and bigger. The *Google Art Project* hosts images of 30,000 x 30,000 Pixels, e.g. [Van Gogh - Starry Night](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Van_Gogh_-_Starry_Night_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends you use the [file stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/gg471497.aspx), for objects over 1MB in size.  Within your table the image will be represented a [VARBINARY(MAX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/swbw1ewb(v=vs.80).aspx) (the normal 2GB limit will not apply).

Comment: @marc_s not according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471497.aspx#storage) : `The standard varbinary(max) limitation of 2-GB file sizes does not apply to BLOBs that are stored in the file system.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: ah - you're right - `FILESTREAM` gets around the 2 GB limit - thanks !

Comment: @marc_s there are [other options as well](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403405(v=sql.110).aspx#CompareFileTable) like FileTables that expose file paths  and the older RBS (remote storage)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `FILETABLE` is based on `FILESTREAM` - it's not something totally new/different ....